# NFA with epsilon transition

Tags: automata, nondeterminism

I need to understand the epsilon transition for [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton_with_%CE%B5-moves), for example I have an NFA with four states `q0`, `q1`, `q2` and `q3` the latter is an accepted state.

In particular the transition function is:

```
{q0, a}= {q1}
{q1, eps}= {q2}
{q2, b}= {q3}
```

I would implementing this behavior in java.

I have the string 'ab' and I have to see if it is accepted. I begin reading the character 'a'  and arrival in the state `q1`, the next character is 'b' but the state `q1` don't have transition for 'b'.

I have to run the epsilon transition as I read the character 'a'?
I do not know how to do this in my application, can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: questions asking for mere implementation in some specific language are off topic here.

Comment: what topic should I add? but logically the epsilon transition I have to read it after reading the letter 'a' or before reading the letter 'b'? thank you very much

Comment: You do the epsilon transition without having read any input

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misconstruing what an $\epsilon$-transition is. If we have, say, a transition rule $\delta(q_1,\epsilon)=\{q_2\}$ it means that the FA can switch from state $q_1$ to $q_2$ *without reading any input*. In your example, on input $ab$ the FA reads the $a$ and so passes from $q_0$ to $q_1$. It can then (in one reality) stay in $q_1$ or (in another), pass to state $q_2$. Then, on seeing the $b$, there is indeed no move from $q_1$ (in one reality) but there is a move (in another reality) to $q_3$, so since the NFA reaches a final state in one reality, the input $ab$ is accepted by the NFA.

Comment: Thank's for your answer.
My question is the transition δ(q1,ϵ)={q2} It must be made before the reading 'b' or after reading 'a'?
Thank for all

Comment: @stella. In your example, you can regard the two as identical.